# Postfix relay to M365: two hosts lists, one auth to send external and other internal only

Tags: postfix

I'm a security admin with mailboxes on Exchange Online (aka Microsoft 365), not seasoned to postmail, but I have to deploy a postmail service on premises to allow some devices (internal applications, switches, etc) to send e-mail through Exchange Online.

My preferred approoach is an internal device (example: printer) or application (ex: some on premises server)  talks SMTP with my on premises postfix that in turn talks SMTP to Exchange Online.

I have everything configured on Exchange side to this, with a relay connector, no problem receiving e-mail.

I configured postfix to relay and at first it's working ok, allowing only hosts on a file to use the service:

`mynetworks = hash:/etc/postfix/hosts_auth_to_relay`

But I want to mantain two authorization lists:

List1: hosts authorized to relay only to Exchange internal mailboxes... The criteria is mail to my domain (example: mycorpdomain.com).

List2: hosts authorized to relay to all domains (i.e.: gmail.com, hotmail.com, etc.com)

I'm struggling with smtpd_recipient_restrictions and smtpd_relay_restrictions but I got all mail denied when using them. Do you know how to state this two authorizations on main.cf?

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved after countless try and error. Here's how:

PLUS: I don't want senders allowed to send anything to localhost, that's why I have that blocked_destinations.

main.cf relevant lines:

```
relay_domains = mydomaincorp.com

relayhost = [mysubdomainonmicrosoft.mail.protection.outlook.com]

mynetworks = hash:/etc/postfix/hosts_auth_to_relay

smtpd_client_restrictions =  check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/hosts_auth_to_relay, check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/hosts_auth_to_level1, reject

smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/blocked_destinations, permit_mynetworks, check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/destinations_level1, reject
```

hosts_auth_to_relay

```
#My server that e-mail all domains
10.0.0.10      OK
```

hosts_auth_to_level1

```
#My server that e-mail only to mydomaincorp.com
10.0.0.20    OK
```

destinations_level1

```
mydomaincorp.com    OK
```

blocked_destinations

```
localhost       REJECT
localhost.mydomaincorp.com    REJECT
```

If I try to send e-mail to mydomaincorp.com from an unlisted host (i.e. 10.0.0.30) the response is `554 5.7.1 <10.0.0.30>: Client host rejected: Access denied`
That's the expected behaviour.

Don't knows if it's the optimal configuration, but at least it works.